# Cannot read property 'commands' of undefiened (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to code in / commands into my discord bot. But I keep on getting this error:

**Cannot read property 'commands' of undefined**

Below I have attached my main.js file, as well as the part that just keeps giving me the error:

**Part that gives me the error**

```js
const getApp = (guildID) => {
    const app = client.api.applications(client.user.id)
    if (guildID) {
        app.guilds(guildID)
    }
}

client.once('ready', async() => {
    client.user.setActivity('FALLBACK BOT, USE THE MAIN CHECKPOINT BOT INSTEAD. THIS IS FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES')

    const commands = await getApp(guildID).commands.get()
        console.log(commands)

    await getApp(guildID).commands.post({
        data: {
            name: 'ping',
            description: 'Shows your current ping.',
        },
    })
});
```

**Here is the full script**

```js
 // Just grabbing some librarys
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Defining the guildID
 const guildID = (process.env.guildID);
// Filtering the command folder so it only includes .js files
const { join } = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
require('./dashboard/server');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const getApp = (guildID) => {
    const app = client.api.applications(client.user.id)
    if (guildID) {
        app.guilds(guildID)
    }
}

client.once('ready', async() => {
    client.user.setActivity('FALLBACK BOT, USE THE MAIN CHECKPOINT BOT INSTEAD. THIS IS FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES')

    const commands = await getApp(guildID).commands.get()
        console.log(commands)

    await getApp(guildID).commands.post({
        data: {
            name: 'ping',
            description: 'Shows your current ping.',
        },
    })
});

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

 mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SRV, {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true,
     useFindAndModify: false
 }).then(()=> {
     console.log('Connected to Database')
 }).catch((err) =>{
     console.log(err);
 })

// Logging into the bot (THIS INCLUDES THE TOKEN SO DONT INCLUDE IT WHEN SENDING MESSAGES)

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Note: I am quite new to JS so. keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Your `getApp()` function doesn't return anything so you are trying to read `commands` property from undefined value.

You have to return you `app.guilds(guildId)` so you can read property from it.

```js
const getApp = (guildID) => {
    const app = client.api.applications(client.user.id)
    if (guildID) {
        app.guilds(guildID)
    }
    return app;
}

client.once('ready', async() => {
    client.user.setActivity('FALLBACK BOT, USE THE MAIN CHECKPOINT BOT INSTEAD. THIS IS FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES')

    const app = getApp(guildID);
    if (app === null) {
        console.error('error');
        return;
    }

    const commands = await app.commands.get()
        console.log(commands)

    await app.commands.post({
        data: {
            name: 'ping',
            description: 'Shows your current ping.',
        },
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now in console it will just say error, and will not show data inside of discord, or in console

Comment: That means `getApp()` return null.

Comment: How are you providing `guildID` to `getApp()`? what is its value?

Comment: guildID is a const as seen above, and I am importing it (not really) using .env files

Comment: ah sorry. I haven't noticed it. Can you check if this variable has expected value? if it has expected value, you will have to check why `app.guilds()` return null

Comment: @CometicLachlan I have updated my answer. Can you check if this code works for you?

Comment: Got this in console:

`(node:15696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: 405: Method Not Allowed
`